# Open Source Static Source Code Analysis Tool (Security Oriented) For Java

Tags: java, android, security, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I am looking for an open source static source code analysis tool that can be used for security  testing of an android application. I need to make sure that my application is PCI compliant.
An example of a non-open source tool is Fortify.
Anyone can help in providing a list of recommended software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMD and FindBugs are some of the best Static code analysers that I have worked on. You can try them. You can add your own rule and delete some of the existing ones from them.

https://www.sparkred.com/blog/open-source-java-static-code-analyzers/

Comment: Actually am looking for some that are more security oriented. I am aware of PMD and FindBugs, but i don't think they fit for security. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you looked into Coverity scan? http://www.webvivant.com/open-source-security.html

Answer (score 1):

There are so many open source tools for Source Code Analysis Tool For Java like Dependometer,FindBugs,QJ-Pro etc.
[For more details with lists.](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-analyzers)
[Another link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)

Comment: Thats a comprehensive list of open source tools , thanks for sharing.